# good source of benchmarking data with project files for Premiere and After Effects

Tags: after-effects, premiere

I've lately enjoyed editing videos using Premier Pro and After Effects, on my 2013 macbook air. It is painfully obvious that my macbook air was not made for this, especially when rendering in After Effects.

This is just a hobby for me and I want to know what kind of system I need to buy to get at least reasonable performance. There is all kinds of advice online, mostly recommending GTX 1080 and i7-6950 etc.. What I really want is a list of benchmarked systems that show render and export times for different systems from macbooks, to mini PCs and high-end custom builds. If the project files used for the benchmarks are available I can then compare against my macbook air and als compare it on systems I'm evaluating myself.

Who can help me out with some good benchmark files and benchmarks?